# Emacs: How to indent multiline statement by one tab only, when not first statement on a line?

Tags: emacs, indentation

I am not sure how to tell Emacs to indent code similar to the following, as shown: (the tab width is 2)

```
gotoxy(1, 2); cout << "one";
gotoxy(3, 4); cout << "this is "
  "split over two lines";
gotoxy(5, 6); cout << "three";
```

The 'statement-cont' variable is set to '+', indicating that I want a single indent, but I end up with this:

```
gotoxy(1, 2); cout << "one";
gotoxy(3, 4); cout << "this is "
                "split over two lines";
gotoxy(5, 6); cout << "three";
```

It is performing the single indent from the start of the statement instead of the start of the line.

How can I tell Emacs to start its indents from the beginning of the previous line rather than whatever column the statement started at?

Comment: Why do you want Emacs to do the wrong thing? It should be making the continuation obviously a continuation of the previous *statement* not merely the previous *line*.

Comment: @drysdam: What is right and wrong is rather subjective - in this case the gotoxy() command should be considered as part of the same statement.  At any rate, the whole reason why the line is being wrapped is to keep it within 80 columns, so by indenting the following line by 70 spaces hardly makes it worth breaking it onto a new line in the first place.  You'll only get 10 characters in before you have to break it again.  I would rather it be broken over two lines with the "wrong" indent than being spread across 10+ lines with the "right" indent.

Comment: Could you group the multi statement lines into paragraphs?  That way, they still stay together, separated from other parts of the program.  Have you got any special reason to write more than one statement per line?

Comment: @vpit3833: Normally I would group them into paragraphs, but in this particular case the code is easier to maintain having them on the same line.  It is important because if the function I am naming `gotoxy` here is forgotten, the log file gets corrupted.  By having them on the same line it stands out enough that the `gotoxy` call is never forgotten!  As @Lindydancer suggested, there are better ways of achieving this which I am now using, so this is just to reduce my frustration levels while maintaining legacy code!

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you are looking for... Anyway, as the `gotoxy` function apparently is doing something to `cout`, why don't you wrap it into a *manip* function and include it in the stream, that way you will 1) one statement on each line, which could be indented properly, 2) get the ability to have longer lines, as you don't have to stop at each `gotoxy`, and 3) it gives you the ability to apply `gotoxy` on any stream.

For example:

```
cout << gotoxy(1, 2) << "one";
cout << gotoxy(3, 4) << "this is "
  "split over two lines";
cout << gotoxy(5, 6) << "three";
```

Or, even simpler:

```
cout << gotoxy(1, 2) << "one"
     << gotoxy(3, 4) << "this is "
  "split over two lines"
     << gotoxy(5, 6) << "three";
```

Both sections were indented in Emacs, by the way.

You can read more about stream manip functions, for example, here: http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/Cplusplus/Custom-Stream-Manipulation-in-C/2/

Comment: Good suggestion.  I have actually done this already for some other projects and it works nicely as you suggest, but unfortunately I am currently maintaining an old code base and don't have the motivation to rewrite large chunks of it right now :-)